# Menu to filter results in Flask

Tags: javascript, html, flask

I'm rather new to programming and super new to Flask. I'm implementing an html page which has a few filters on the left and it shows the results on the right.
For example a filter might be "2 people room". Selecting it, it would show only 2 people rooms in the div on the right.

All my data is in a DB.

What's the best way to implement it?

I'm thinking of this way:
- Implement onclick JS function that, when clicking on 2people room filter, it would select a subset of the data (only the 2 people rooms) and then create html for all that data (in Jinja2).

Is here a better way to do so?
thanks

Comment: What kind of database is it?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a HTML checkbox.

You could then have some JavaScript that displays the results based on which checkboxes are checked or not.

EDIT

I have quickly made a form here, using pure HTML/JavaScript. What you could do is make a GET request to your flask server using the contents of `array`. Or just make a basic SQL query to your database: `SELECT houses FROM table WHERE rooms=array`. ( That's not a valid SQL query, you will have to pass in the numbers properly)

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
<body>

<p>Filter Menu</p>

<form action="/action_page.php">
<input type="checkbox" name="room" value="0">Studio<br>
<input type="checkbox" name="room" value="1">One bed<br>
<br>
<input type="button" onclick="myFunction()" value="update filter">
</form>

<script>
function myFunction() {
  var form = document.forms[0];
  var array = [];
  var i;
  for (i = 0; i < form.length; i++) {
    if (form[i].checked) {
      array.push(form[i].value);
    }
  }
  console.log(array)
  // Make an SQL query with array
}
</script>

</body>
</html>
```

Comment: thanks, but when do I perform the filtering of data? inside the js onclick function?

Comment: @pasqpasq check my code - this might give you a good starting point